# get list from fireStore in flutter app with indexes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a list from firestore but i had a problem with indexes.

This is the structure of the normal Items on the List and every object contain a list of items:

```
class RestaurantFoodList { 
    final String id ; 
    final String title; 
    List <RestaurantitemList> items ; 
    final String imageUrl;

    RestaurantFoodList({this.id,this.title,this.items,this.imageUrl}); 
}
```

This is the structure of the items themselfs:

```
class RestaurantitemList { 
    final String id ; 
    final String title ; 
    final String imageUrl ; 
    final String description ; 
    final int price ; 
    final int shippingPrice;
    List<Checkbox> cheker;

    RestaurantitemList({this.id,this.title,this.imageUrl,this.description,this.price,this.shippingPrice,this.cheker});
}
```

---

This is how i add the object in firestore:

```
Future<void> addLitem(RestaurantFoodList foodList, RestaurantitemList itemList) async {
    final _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
    _fireStore.collection('restaurant').add({
        'title': foodList.title,
        'imageUrl': foodList.imageUrl,
        'items': [
            {
                'id': itemList.id,
                'title': itemList.title,
                'imageUrl': itemList.imageUrl,
            }
         ],
    });
}
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZZi.png) is my firestore data, my problem is how can i fetch All list and their items correctly, i tried this but it didn't work:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetList() async {
    final List<RestaurantFoodList> loadedList = [];

    await Firestore.instance.collection("restaurant").getDocuments().then(
          (QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach(
            (f) => loadedList.insert(
              0,
              RestaurantFoodList(
                  id: f.data['id'],
                  imageUrl: f.data['imageUrl'],
                  title: f.data['title'],
                  items: [f.data['items']]

              ),
            ),
          ),
    );

    notifyListeners();
    _restaurantItems[3].itemsList = loadedList;

}
```

note : if i write another method to get Items i must write

```
items: loadedItem.add(RestaurantitemList(
    id : f.data['items'][0]['id']
))
```

but i want to get all the list of items not just one item so the approach of the index here i think it's a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted the first answer and I am adding a new one (will edit this line out once you see it).

So, there are a few problems with your `fetchAndSetList` function, and I rewrote it:

```
Future < void > fetchAndSetList() async {
    final List < RestaurantFoodList > loadedList = [];
    final List < RestaurantitemList > itemList = [];

    await Firestore.instance.collection("restaurant").getDocuments().then(
        (QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => {
            itemList = [];
            f.data['items'].forEach((i) =>
                itemList.add(RestaurantitemList(
                    id: i.id,
                    title: i.title,
                    imageUrl i.imageUrl
                    // you might need to add all fields here, even if they are null
                )
            ); 
            loadedList.add(RestaurantFoodList(
                id: f.data['id'],
                imageUrl: f.data['imageUrl'],
                title: f.data['title'],
                items: itemList
            ))
        });
    );

    notifyListeners();

}
```

What have I changed?

- Added the `itemList` variable, a list of `RestaurantitemList` that you will add to your final `loadedList`;
- Added to the original forEach a second forEach that populates the itemList with your `RestaurantitemList` objects, I also added a comment stating that you should add all the fields that you have mapped on the `RestaurantitemList` object;
- I changed the `loadedList.insert` to `loadedList.add`, so you don't have to worry about what position the record is being added to.

**NOTE**: this is untested, but it should fix the issues that were having.

Comment: thank you very much sir for your rsponse but it didn't work i think because my itemsList the are mapped and automaticly, in firestore it give them numbers i want to make them as map<int , dynamic > but i don't know the structure

Comment: if can i contact privatly please et me how